# How to get ID by username - Twitter API Python

Tags: python, twitter, python-twitter

I'm creating an application with the Python Twitter API Package ([python-twitter](https://python-twitter.readthedocs.io)) but need to convert from username `@username` to ID `bunch_of_letters`.

I've searched far and wide in the docs but just couldn't find how to do this. Would I need to just do a search? If so, how do I filter it so only users appear? Or should I do this through a request, because there is no functionality for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out. Use `GetUser(screen_name = "name")`.

Use the `screen_name` argument, instead of `user_id`. `screen_name` should be the user's username, without `@`.